# mvc3 detect website (application) is closing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, window

I'm building a website with mvc3 and I need to delete a data in my database only when the application is closing. (The user click on the red x).

I tried with javascript using the onbeforeunload event, but this event happens everytime I go into a new page in my application.

Is it possible to detect when the user closes the window?

Comment: It can be done, but I don't know how (not a JS expert).  However, I have seen that behavior before on web pages.  Make sure your application logic does not DEPEND on the behavior though.  What happens if the browser crashes or the person just walks away until after the session times out?

Comment: Okok, well I think I still need to do some works then, because in my website, 2 users can see the same document, the first one can edit it, but the second user can only read the document. So I add in a database the id of the document and when the second user open the document, I check if it is in the database (mean its in use). So when the first user exit the website I need to delete the reference in the database so other users can edit it too. :S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible. But, what you can do is have a small javascript block that will make an ajax call every *n* minutes/seconds to tell the server that the user still has the browser open.

This way, you can set a timeout that says if after 5 minutes we haven't heard from the user we can delete the data in the database (or whatever action you need to do).

To implement the timeout logic there are 2 options:

1. You have a separate service (console app or windows service) running on some interval that checks if any user's timeout is greater than some value. If it is then perform whatever action you need.
2. If *any* user performs an action that would have been blocked, you first check if any user still has it active (the timeout value is greater than current time). If there is, you block the user, if there isn't, you can remove that old timeout value since it's expired.

Comment: Thank you, this is going to help me out ^^

Answer (score 3):

Use a synchronous ajax request in the window.unload event.

When the user goes to a different page, or closes, or refreshes then this event will fire.  You could call a service on your web app to notify it that the user is no longer editing the document

After a very quick google, I saw this snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231457/synchronous-ajax-post-from-unload-event-how-to-ensure-user-sees-most-up-to-date)

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'resetTheDocument?id=whatever',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: "My work here is done"
    });
});
```

Comment: This could work, but you'd have to change it to detect only when the browser is closed and not when they're going to a different page or refreshing since the OP said he doesn't want it to happen then.

Comment: Yah I need this to happens only when the window closes not when I go in a different page.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning you could try adding your logic to the global.asax file in the Session_End method to delete the record in your database.

Comment: I've tried putting my logic in the global.asax Application_End() but nothing happen when I close the application, but the Session_end is working

Comment: Be aware though that the session doesn't end when the user closes the browser, it ends when the session timeout is reached.